# C# issue when calculating a reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I put together this little script whose goal is to calculate a reference according to the document type chosen in a form, and to concatenate a number that's auto-incremented. I am however getting this error when saving:

> the string or binary data would be truncated

```
string typeDocAbbr = doc.GetStringValue("Document_type_Abbr"); 
string textRef = doc.GetStringValue("text_reference");

if (typeDocAbbr == "DIV")
    returnValue = string.Format("{0}-{1}", typeDocAbbr, textRef);

if ((typeDocAbbr == "FIC") || (typeDocAbbr == "FTC") || (typeDocAbbr == "FDP"))
    returnValue = string.Format("{0}-{1}", typeDocAbbr, textRef);


else
{ 
    int chrono = 0; 
    string schrono = ""; 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.GetStringValue("Reference")))
    { 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeDocAbbr))
        { 
            EDITOR.Documents.DataSource.ChronoManagerWrapper cmw = 
                new EDITOR.Documents.DataSource.ChronoManagerWrapper(); 
            string Key = typeDocAbbr;
            chrono = cmw.GetNewChrono("Process Studio", Key); 
            if (chrono < 10) 
                schrono = "0" + chrono.ToString();
            else 
                schrono = chrono.ToString()}; 
        } 
    } 
    returnValue = string.Format("{0}-{1}", typeDocAbbr, schrono); 
}
```

Comment: that's what the debugger is for....(and unit tests)

Comment: String or binary data would be truncated is a message from Sql Server, indicating you are trying to save a value which is too long for the field. Check your db. The code you posted probably has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Now that your code is readable ... are you missing an `else` before the second `if`? As it is now if `typeDocAbbr == "DIV"`, `returnvalue` will be overwritten in the `else` block.

Comment: this is an sql exception. but  i see no code saving to db. are you sure the exception is happening here

Answer (score 0):

This error :

```
the string or binary data would be truncated
```

is NOT on the code you shown. It is a SQL Server error.
It means that DB field is too small for the value you tried to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Okay people, my bad. 
I actually figured out where I went wrong. The `returnValue` of the script I shared went to feed a column the max size of which was 10 for some reason. However, as some of you so nicely pointed out to a beginner like me, the error was originating from the table, not the script, indicating that the value was too big for the column (that's what she said). 
Thank you for some constructive criticism!